# nc Won't Listen on a Port on CentOs6

Tags: netcat

I'm playing with nc for the file transfer function. On a CentOS6 machine, If I put nc on the listening mode, it returns a help message instead.

It seems nc with older visions needs different parameters?

```
[root@test ~]# nc -nlvp 4444
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
[root@test ~]# nc -n -l -v -p 4444
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
[root@test ~]# rpm -qa|grep nc
nc-1.84-24.el6.x86_64
```

Downgrade to an older version doesn't help
https://serverfault.com/questions/729746/netcat-fails-to-start-in-listening-mode

Comment: I don't see a __security__ question here, i.e. off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-p [port]` is for specifying the source port number for an outbound connection, not for specifying on which port you want to listen. Remove that from the command and it will work:

```
nc -nlv 4444
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why I can use the "p" option on newer Linux versions?